# what do you call the person who passes the trophies to the prize giver/presenter?

Tags: nouns

The person who gives out the trophies to the winners are called award presenters. So what do u call the person who passes the trophies to the presenter?

Thanks!

Comment: I will be surprised if there is a more specific word than *helper* or *assistant*

Answer (score -3):

The person who gives out the trophies to the winners are called award presenters. So what do u call the person who passes the trophies to the presenter?

May be Usher.

### 2. [n] someone employed to conduct others .

http://lookwayup.com/lwu.exe/lwu/d?s=f&w=usher#v/1364900

Comment: If you do not know the answer, please do make make one up.  As yo've said: an usher conducts *people*, e.g. in a cinema. The question is about passing a trophy from one person to another - NOT about *conducting people*!

Comment: I humbly disagree .. Conducting in this context meant conducting  or guiding the presenter about which trohpy is

Comment: I humbly disagree with you.. Conducting in this context meant conducting  or guiding the presenter about which trophy is to be given to whom. "Usher" is also an assistant or a doorkeeper.

Comment: I can;t see that meaning in the reference you've given.

Comment: Unfortunately an usher ***ushers***.  This means to *escort* or *guide*.  I'd call the person who hands trophies to the presenter, an ***assistant***.