# What do you call people who give out awards, certificates and trophies?

Tags: terminology

I give out awards on a daily basis. However, I never knew the actual terminology for the person who hands out awards. I was thinking of *awarder* but that doesn't seem right.

Comment: Is that an _actual job_?

Comment: Yes. It is an actual job. Well, it is part of the real job I have.

Comment: So it is a _function_ of your job.

Comment: Yes. It is a function of my job.

Comment: Related: [what do you call the person who passes the trophies to the prize giver/presenter?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/338885/what-do-you-call-the-person-who-passes-the-trophies-to-the-prize-giver-presenter).

Comment: Please reread your question and correct the English grammatical error.

Comment: There are no grammatical errors as it was reviewed.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to [*Merriam-Webster*](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/presenter), it is ***a presenter:***

> one who presents something : a person who formally gives or bestows something (such as an award) or who brings something before the public
>   // The *presenter* of the award for Best Actress was the actress who won the award last year.

[This site](https://www.backstage.com/magazine/article/prepare-awards-presenter-44174/) uses ***an awards presenter.*** If the people to whom you are describing your job are likely to be British English speakers, it is better to use this longer phrase, as in British English, a *presenter* is

> a television or radio broadcaster who delivers news or information to an audience ([*Merriam-Webster*](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/presenter))

A related concept is that of an ***MC*** (master of ceremonies). Again from [*Merriam-Webster*](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/master%20of%20ceremonies):

> :a person who acts as host at a formal event
>   :a person who acts as host for a program of entertainment (as on television)